# DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml does exist when publishing using Amazon Elastic Beantalk in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to publish and debug my ASP.NET 4.5 on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk but I get the following error message:

```
 Copying file bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml failed. Could not find file 'bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml'.
```

I am looking at the bin folder and I can see that the file `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.xml` does exist in that folder. The error returned by AWS when I publishes my application to Elastic Beanstalk via Visual Studio.

I am developing my app in ASP.NET 4.5 as a project not a website in visual studio. Thanks.